# How to create a view based on its content in constraint layout?

Tags: android, android-constraintlayout

I have a view which needs to be shown at the bottom and also view height should be based on the content (the view's linked with parent). If I link the top constraint of `error_view` with parent, then its entire space is used.

what is the use of `constraintLayout` inside `constraintLayout` and when we should go? Is this solution match for my problem?

[image]

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ...>
     <View
        android:id="@+id/error_view"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="160dp"  // How to keep height based on content rather than defined height??
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
        android:background="@drawable/display_result"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/textureView"
       />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/error_msg"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
        android:text="@string/error_msg"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/error_try_again"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/error_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/error_view"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/error_view" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/error_try_again"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
        android:background="@drawable/primary_button"
        android:text="@string/try_again"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/error_view"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/error_view"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/error_view" />
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use nested constraint layout or you can use any other ViewGroup like RelativeLayout, LinearLayout etc according to your needs.

In your case, As you View height should be according to the content so you can not fix it height.
Suggested solutions is:

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout ...>
    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
           android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="40dp"
            android:background="@drawable/display_result">
          <TextView
            android:id="@+id/error_msg"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="12dp"
            android:fontFamily="@font/poppins_medium"
            android:text="@string/error_msg"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="@color/white"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/error_try_again"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/error_view"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/error_view"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/error_view" />
    
        <Button
            android:id="@+id/error_try_again"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_marginEnd="12dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="24dp"
            android:background="@drawable/primary_button"
            android:text="@string/try_again"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@+id/error_view"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/error_view"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/error_view" />
    </constraint>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Comment: Is constraint layout meant for a `flat view hierarchy`? I mean is it possible to do without `nested viewGroup`?

Comment: ^ it say https://medium.com/@jemli.idea/constraintlayout-never-ever-97c121286100#5e02

Comment: If our requirements is expand parent view height according to the content than obviously we need to use nested view.
We can use constraint layout and inside it we can use RelativeLayout or LinearLayout etc according to the need.
Its not compulsory to use nested constraintlayout.

Comment: I have read this article but for this requirement nested viewgroup is needed.

Comment: I have one doubt. How can we do animation on nested constraints with this approach? Bcz `ConstraintSet` is not working on the nested one.